# Refer to another tab bar within iOS application

Tags: ios, authentication, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application with a login screen on a UIWebView and then when the user is logged in all the other tabs are able to use the same login.
The login button is also on the website and I have no control over that code.

Now if a user is not logged in then the other tabs give an error, but I was wondering if i could do an if statement, comparing the active tab to the first, to see if the login page is displayed. so the idea would look like this.

```
if(tab bar 1 == index.html) {
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
else{
NSString *urlAddress = @"website that is requested";    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

What do I put in the () after the if statement?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]; will return the view controller for the first tab. Make the web view a property of the view controller. Then:

```
UIViewController *loginViewController = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
UIWebView *loginWebView [loginViewController webView];
NSString *currentURL = [loginWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];

if (currentURL == someURL) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this option tomorrow and provide my feedback thanks.